# Repository does not have a release file (Kubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, updates, apt-get, kubuntu, repository

I have attached a screenshot of the message I get when using sudo apt-get update.

I attempted to use the repositories in the past but did not succeed. I now wish to get rid of these messages.

Any advice on where to go and remove these entries? Probably a config file I have to edit.

[image]

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/falk-t-j/qtsixa/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/materieller/teamspeak3/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I am using Kubuntu version 19.04, KDE PLasma version 5.15.4

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be better to post the text of the screenshot instead of the screenshot, as a search engine is not able to parse the image. Please also describe which version of Kubuntu you are using.

Comment: I edited my original post so it contains Kubuntu version and also thje actual terminal text. Sorry I had trouble formatting the text

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it myself. I just unticked the software sources in the Software and Updates application in UBuntu. Thanks all

Comment: You should accept your own answer, so that it is clear, that this question is answered.